# Streaming MJPEG from browser on iOS

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mjpeg

After spending some hours searching a solution to the non-working `drawImage` for canvas in HTML5 i am stuck without a solution. Basically i am running a MJPEG server i need to stream its contents from either `Safari` or `Chrome`.

Is there a solution that does not involve creating a native app?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Well in a sense i did. Its impossible, unless you make an native app, which is a showstopper for my web application.